# Testing bitterness during boil

Tags: hops, recipe, boil, bittering

Will be modifying a recipe and while I know the alpha % of the bittering hops and this being the first time I'm altering a recipe I'm wondering during the boiling process have I added enough bittering hops or do I need more.

Can I assume that 30 minutes into a 60 minute boil the wort should be twice as bitter at the end of the boil?

Lets say I haven't added enough bittering hops, what can I do?
What if I've added to much?

I"m trying to find out if I can use any guidelines while the boil is going on.

The recipe is the northern brewer dead ringer (all-grain) with cascade hops (10% alpha).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bitterness is not linear throughout the boil](http://www.realbeer.com/hops/research.html), so you cannot assume that it will be twice as bitter after 60 minutes vs. 30 minutes.  I'm also not sure that you're going to get a great sense of the bitterness in the partially-boiled wort vs. the finished beer, but I don't have a really compelling argument as to why not.

But I'm not understanding something about your question. If you have a recipe that adds A amount of B AA% hops at time C to achieve a computed IBU value D … why not use those parameters to figure out what you need to do for your modified recipe?  If you want more IBUs, then adjust. If you're using different hops with a different AA%, then adjust.

At least from what I've seen from other brewers, this is something you adjust brew-to-brew, not within a brew itself.

Comment: The perception of bitterness will be affected by the sweetness of the wort. It will taste considerably less bitter than the finished beer.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with that statement Tobias. Theoretically you should be correct, but almost every wort sample I've tasted was like bitter orange marmalade. I think wort can have hop particles in suspension, which is why it can taste so bitter.

Comment: I'm just trying to see what options I have during the boil, which doesn't seem like much. I have the recipe in beersmith and adjusted it for the new hops, this is just the first time I've done this and I'm also just curious.

Comment: I don't think it's so much hop particles in suspension as that as the beer ferments, interaction between the yeast and hops "tames" the bitterness.